# match everything before the longest sequence of lowercase letters

Tags: python, regex

Say that I have some expressions as the following: `4a1.602.9015zetjre735pA`.
 I want to match everything that's before the longest sequence of lowercase letters (i.e `4a1.602.9015`).

With some googling, I ended up to this regex: `re.search(r'.+?(?=[a-z]{2,})', expression)`.
Except that in the general situation, the longest sequence of lowercase letters has not a fix length (it can be 2, 3, or more letters). Which means it is possible to have expressions like this: `4afj1.602.9015zmpetjre735pA`. And in this case, my regex will not work (using my regex with the previous expression, the result will be just `4`).

I found another solution: `match = max(re.findall(r'[a-z]+', expression), key=len)` then take the part of the expression that's before it (`f_match = expresion[:expression.index(match)]`).  But it is not a pure regex.
Is there any pure regex solution?

Comment: The solution you have is right. Regex cannot find the longest or shortest matches in a text by itself.

Comment: you would need a more extended approach, *pure* regex won't make magic here. Just choose the most optimal functional approach along with regex

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments, I'll keep using my second solution then.

Comment: Is the longest expression is always the last one?

Comment: @singrium, feel free to post your second approach if it requires optimization (if you have performance concerns)

Comment: @CharifDZ, generally, it is not the last one, but your question might give me a hint to do some pre-processing to make it the last one. This would make things easier.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I already posted it in my question: `max(re.findall(r'[a-z]+', expression), key=len)` then take the expression's part that it is before that.